# Powershell Script to Capitalize a letter in the middle of a file name

Tags: powershell

I was looking for a way adjust the following:

- Name S01e01.mp4
- Name s01e02.mp4
- Name s01e03.mp4

Is there a way to capitalize the S and E ??

- Name S01E01.mp4
- Name S01E02.mp4
- Name S01E03.mp4

I have tried the below but it replaces all E's resulting in:

```
dir -recurse | where {-Not $_.PsIscontainer -AND $_.name -match "."} | 
foreach {
$New=$_.Basename.Replace(" s"," S").Replace("e","E")+$_.Extension
Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
}
```

- NamE S01E01.mp4
- NamE S01E02.mp4
- NamE S01E03.mp4

Thank you so much in advance.

UPDATE:

```
cd C:\Users\test\Desktop\test
PS C:\Users\test\Desktop\test> dir -recurse | where {-Not $_.PsIscontainer -AND $_.name -match "."} |
>> foreach {
>> $New = $_.Name -replace '(.* )s(\d{2})e(\d{2}\..*)', '$1S$2E$3'
>> Rename-Item -path $_.Fullname -newname $New -passthru
>> }


    Directory: C:\Users\test\Desktop\test


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/25/2018   2:32 PM              0 Test.Of.Testing.S01e01.this.X264.Mp4
-a----        1/25/2018   2:32 PM              0 Test.Of.Testing.S01E01.this.X264.Mp4
-a----        1/25/2018   2:33 PM              0 Test.Of.Testing.S01e31.this.X264.Mp4
-a----        1/25/2018   2:33 PM              0 Test.Of.Testing.s01E01.this.X264.Mp4
```

This is what I currently get after swapping in the suggestion from mklement0, it almost looks like nothing changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach didn't work, because the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method invariably replaces *all* (literal) matches.

Instead, use PowerShell's `-replace` operator, which is regex-based (using a single file name as an example):

```
> 'Name s01e01.mp4' -replace '(.*\b)s(\d{2})e(\d{2}\b.*)', '$1S$2E$3'
Name S01E01.mp4
```

For a concise summary of `-replace`'s behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) of mine.

Note:

- For simplicity, the regex above is designed to match the entire filename, including extension; in the context of the code posted in the question the line therefore needs to be:
  `$New = $_.Name -replace '(.*\b)s(\d{2})e(\d{2}\b.*)', '$1S$2E$3'`
- `-replace` is the same as `-ireplace`; that is, matching is case-*insensitive*. Thus, if both the `s` and the `e` in question already are uppercased, the replacement is an effective no-op; however, if either or both are lowercased, the replacement ensures that they are uppercased.

---

To put it all together, using PSv3+ syntax:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -Recurse -File |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(.*\b)s(\d{2})e(\d{2}\b.*)', '$1S$2E$3' }
```

Note:

- The PSv3+ `-File` switch makes `Get-ChildItem` return *files* only (similarly, you can ask for *directories* only with `-Directory`).
- `*.*` as the (implied) `-Path` argument only matches filenames that contain at least one period (`.`), which I presume was your *intent*; by contrast, your attempt to do the same with `-match '.'` would have matched *all* filenames, because metacharacter `.` in a regex represents *any* single char.

  - On a side note: passing `*.*` to the `-Filter` rather than to the `-Path` argument also matches *all* filenames, because it is then the Windows API that interprets the wildcard expression, not PowerShell, and for backward-compatibility reasons `*.*` is treated the same as `*`.
- There is no need for a `foreach` (`ForEach-Object`) loop, because `Rename-Item` can accept `Get-ChildItem`'s output directly.

Comment: im importing the string from file names, so the S00E00 will change, is there a way to just seperate the string or tell my powershell script to ignore capitalization when it runs?

Comment: What, specifically, will change? The current answer matches any 2-digit sequences with `\d{2}`. I don't know what you mean by your 2nd sentence.

Comment: When i use your line in place of my $New it removes the extension and doesnt change anything, so I guess im not sure how to incorporate your line into my existing code above.

Comment: @DefcaTrick: Please see my update. The previous regex didn't work, because you quietly changed the premise of the question: your original sample filename had a _space_ before the `s\d{2}e\d{2}` substring, whereas the filenames in the sample command you added later had a _period_. I've generalized the regex to now match at _word boundaries_ with `\b`, which should cover both cases. Please note that it is important to provide _representative_ sample input, including a description of the variations that can occur. Finally, see the simplified version of your overall command at the bottom.